# error: ‘foo’ is not captured Lambda function and boost integration

Tags: c++, boost, integration, numerical-methods

Im triyng to perform a numerical integral using Boost Library quadrature. I did it using trapezoidal like this

```
double integrand(double xp, double yp, double x, double y, double a, double b) {
    double eps;
    if(x - xp == 0 && y - yp == 0)
        eps = 1e-6;
    else
        eps = 0.0;

    return std::log(std::hypot(x - xp + eps, y - yp + eps)) * w(xp, yp);
}
double integrate(double x, double y, double a, double b) {
    auto inner_integral = [m, n, a, b](double yp) {
        auto f = [z, m, n, a, b](double xp) { return integrand(xp, yp, x, y, a, b); };
        return boost::math::quadrature::trapezoidal(f, 0.0, a, 1e-8);
    };
    return boost::math::quadrature::trapezoidal(inner_integral, 0.0, b, 1e-8);
}
```

This works fine but because we have an indetermination close to log(0) it takes a lot of time, so I searched for an alternative. In Boost, they have some integration methods for this kind of situation, so I decided to try [tanh_sinh](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/double_exponential/de_tanh_sinh.html) method. I implemented it like this following the given example.

```
double Integrate(double x, double y, double a, double b) {
    boost::math::quadrature::tanh_sinh<double> integrator;
    auto inner_integral = [x, y, a, b](double yp) {
        auto f = [yp, x, y, a, b](double xp) { return integrand(xp, yp, x, y, a, b); };
        return integrator.integrate(f, 0.0, a);
    };
    return integrator.integrate(inner_integral, 0.0, b);
}
```

The problem is that when I compile it says `error: ‘integrator’ is not captured` followed with `note: the lambda has no capture-default`  and a huge error.

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is exactly what it says. Your lambda isn't capturing `integrator`. Change `[x,y,a,b]` to `[x,y,a,b,integrator]` to capture by value or `[x,y,a,b,&integrator]` to capture by reference.

Alternatively you can capture everything by value with `[=]` or everything by reference with `[&]`.

See [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) for syntax.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks. I'm not very familiar with Lambda functions, dint knows what that error ment.

Comment: @CarlosAndrésdelValle: Yes. Please accept the answers if your query is resolved. Otherwise people will lose interest to post the answers.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @CarlosAndrésdelValle Click the checkmark to the left of my answer, just below the upvote/downvote buttons.